# Mongoid, setting custom accessor field in mongoid-history gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm adding `mongoid-history gem` to my project.

According to guide [in github](https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history), when I add `Userstamp` to my tracker it creates `created_by` field with accessor called `creator`.

They have written that I can rename it via gem config.

How to rename this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation, Userstamp is another gem called [mongoid_userstamp](https://github.com/tbpro/mongoid_userstamp). The documentation provided the sample code to configure the names via config file or inside each model:

config/mongoid_userstamp.rb:

```
# Default config (optional unless you want to customize the values)
Mongoid::Userstamp.config do |c|
  c.user_reader = :current_user
  c.created_name = :created_by
  c.updated_name = :updated_by
end
```

app/models/your_model.rb

```
# Example model class
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Userstamp

  # optional class-level config override
  # mongoid_userstamp user_model: 'MyUser',
  #                   created_name: :creator,
  #                   updated_name: :updater,
end

# Example user class
class MyUser
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Userstamp::User

  # optional class-level config override
  # mongoid_userstamp_user reader: :current_my_user
end
```

In Mongoid History, you can include the configuration inside the HistoryTracker class, for example:

```
# app/models/history_tracker.rb
class HistoryTracker
  include Mongoid::History::Tracker
  include Mongoid::Userstamp
  # optional class-level config override
  mongoid_userstamp created_name: :updater,
                    updated_name: :another_updater,
end
```

Comment: Why you placed `Mongoid::Userstamp` on your tracking model? I thought it is only needed for your tracking class? If I want change `creator` to `updater`?

Comment: Editted the answer to fit the code in HistoryTracker class.

Comment: when I try to use it with `mongoid-audit` gem, it thorws me `undefined method `updater'` error

Comment: Did you uncomment the lines of  `mongoid_userstamp`? Sorry I forgot to update the code properly.